# A regular expression to match and exclude

Tags: regex

I've been scraping pages to compile a list to compare prices and dimensions. I've been using only widthxlength, excluding height. However some measurements come with height and sometimes decimals, such as:

5.0x10.0x8.0

10.0x10.0x9.0

10.0x15.0x9.0

10.0x20.0x9.0

I'm trying to exclude the .0's and the last dimension. To only end up with:

5x10
10x10
10x15
10x20

I've used `\d+[ ][X][ ]\d+` and `(\d+'x\d+')` for similar problems, but I'm having trouble finding a way to crack this.

Comment: Please explain which programming language or tool you are using.

Comment: Is this an "extraction" question or a "replacement" question?  You have already scraped, right? You just need to replace what is scraped?  I'm sure I don't know what you are doing with those single quotes in your attempted pattern -- what programming language are you using?  We can only assume that we are working with individual scraped strings, so if you want us to help with accurate scraping, you'll need to offer some realistic sample text.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the whole string, capturing the integer part of the width and length, and replace with the two capture groups. Match

```
(\d+)\.\d+x(\d+)\.\d+(?:x\d+\.\d+)?
```

and replace with

```
$1x$2
```

https://regex101.com/r/BOkRx6/3

If the decimal part may not exist, then put each decimal part in the pattern into an optional non-capturing group:

```
(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?x(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?(?:x\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/BOkRx6/4